# @font-face custom icons font code works when put in :before pseudo class, but not :after, why?

Tags: html, css, icon-fonts, fontello

I generated a list of custom icons from fontello, and I needed 2 make 2 icons stacked (because I needed the two in different colours).

Originally, I had it wrapped in a container that's in relative position, with the two icons as their own object in absolute position -- that works, however, when I sent it to the developers, they request it be in one object, because otherwise they have to change a list of angular code, blah blah blah.

So I was thinking of using the :before and :after.  For example:

```
<i class ="icon-one icon-two">

.icon-one:before {
content: '\787';
}
.icon-two:after {
content: '\666';
}
```

However, the same code I put in the before would work, but when I change the pseudo class to :after, it's broken and left with a big rectangle on the page.  I can't figure out why that is.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: You should add a bigger code sample, or live link for the issue. Based on a blind guess, you probably have a `font-family` set to your icon-font only on `:before` selector. Also, test with the same working icon, to exclude the possibility of wrong icon character code.

Comment: You're right.  That was the problem.  Someone from the fontello user group helped me solved it.

Comment: @CleverNode Comments suggested you solved this -- can you share that?